# Python DataType converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

making a random converter, but need to get it to return `None` and print 'cannot be converted' when it attempts to change string to integer, string to complex etc. but can't use `Try: Except:` ruling.

```
import random


def random_converter(x):
    selection = random.randint(1,5)
    if selection == 1:
        return int(x)
    elif selection == 2:
        return float(x)
    elif selection == 3:
        return bool(x)
    elif selection == 4:
        return str(x)
    else:
        return complex(x)

for _ in range(50):
    output = random_converter('007')
    print(output, type(output))
```

If the datatype can't be converted then it should return `None` and print 'Cannot be converted' but can't use `Try: except:`

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Try-except is the standard way to do this, so why can't you use it? Is this a homework problem? If so read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework", and [ask] more generally. Also you haven't actually asked a question. I'm inferring you're asking *how*, but it would help if you made that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to used isinstance

```
def random_converter(x):
    selection = random.randint(1,5)
    if selection == 1:
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return int(x)
    elif selection == 2:
        if isinstance(x, float):
            return float(x)
    elif selection == 3:
        if isinstance(x, bool):
            return bool(x)
    elif selection == 4:
        if isinstance(x,str):
            return str(x)
    elif selection == 5:
        if isinstance(x,complex):
            return complex(x)
    print("Can not be converted")
    return None
```

Comment: This doesn't do any conversion at all... I think OP's actually asking how to handle `ValueError`s without using try-except.

Comment: Agree. This function is not a conversion, the requested behavior is strange... I wanted to point out that using `isinstance` is a solution to handle types without exceptions.